# How do I run a SQL query in Databricks Spark, querying a column entitled "like", when "like" is also a SQL term?

Tags: sql

I just tried running the following SQL query in databricks spark:

```
SELECT 
        uid_1,
        uid_2,
        CASE WHEN like IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS liked
FROM relevant_table
```

I run into an error message because "like" is also a SQL term. When working in redshift, one can simply put "like" in double quotes to resolve this issue, but that doesn't work with databricks spark. What's the fix here?

Comment: Chose another column name.

Comment: It should have given you an error because you didn't `end` your case expression. I don't think "like" is the problem here, but what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with spark, but maybe escaping with backticks does the trick:

```
SELECT ds,
       st,
       uid,
       other_id,
       CASE WHEN `like` IS TRUE OR super_like IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS liked,
       s_number
FROM   tinder_events.recs_rate_20228
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Databricks needs special treatment of your column named "like". You could double-quote it or use backticks, but I don't believe it should matter.

The problem with the query is that it's a missing the `END` to the case expression. I believe that will resolve your error.

```
SELECT ds,
        st,
        uid,
        other_id,
        CASE WHEN like IS TRUE OR super_like IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS liked,
        s_number
FROM tinder_events.recs_rate_20228
```